# javafx media player video Ending not working

Tags: java, javafx

When Launching the app , directly an intro video kicks in,

I have 2 scenarios :

1. Watch Full intro , then automatically redirect to another page
2. Click Skip button to get instantly redirected to another page

both of these 2 scenarios are working flawlessly when I run the app from the IDE,

but when a package the app to jar format the first scenario never work ( see the code for more details )

the Class :

```
public class SplashScreenController implements Initializable {


    @FXML
    private HBox introView;



    @FXML
    private Label btSkipIntro;


    MediaPlayer player;

   @Override
   public void initialize(URL location, ResourceBundle resources) {



      // INTRO VIDEO PROCESS ------------------------
      player = new MediaPlayer(new Media(getClass().getResource("/Images/SeffirIntro.mp4").toExternalForm()));
      MediaView mediaView = new MediaView(player);

      mediaView.setPreserveRatio(true);
      mediaView.setSmooth(true);

     introView.getChildren().add(mediaView);

     System.out.println("Started");

     player.play();

     player.setOnEndOfMedia(() -> {

          System.out.println("Ended");

          try {
               // Code to automatically redirect to another page
               Entry.viewNavigator.openView("/Views/LanguageView.fxml");
          } catch (IOException e) {
               e.printStackTrace();
        }

    });



  @FXML  // When the skip button clicked
  public void skipClicked() throws IOException{
      System.out.println("Skipped");
      player.stop();
      Entry.viewNavigator.openView("/Views/LanguageView.fxml");

  }
```

in my IDE testing the ( player.setOnEndOfMedia lambda function executes beautifly) but when the jar executes that function is never accessed.

The JAR creation was tested with both maven and the artifact build , both same result the function after when the video ends , doesn't fire

any explanation on why is this issue is happening will be of great help

thanx in advance

Comment: How the JAR file is being created, can you add more info?

Comment: @Boris lm creating the JAR using ' build artifact ' under Build in Intellij

Comment: Ok, can you compare the two outputs of running the app in the IntelliJ and as a JAR. What's the difference?

Comment: @Boris the difference is that in Intellij the function ( player.setOnEndOfMedia ) is fired when the video finished , but the the JAR doesn't fire when the video ends

Comment: Sorry, I meant the console/log output. Maybe there is some difference we could spot?

Comment: @Boris actually the console output never raised any exception, but i have found a fix to my problem , thank you for your responses

Comment: I advice you to post your answer, the community might like it and upvote it.